# gaps and islands with date format

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table like this:

| ma_id | act_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 |
| 1 | 2023-01-03 |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 |
| 1 | 2023-01-06 |
| 2 | 2023-02-08 |
| 2 | 2023-02-09 |

I have read a lot of guides but couldn't find what I was looking for...
I want a result like this:

| ma_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-03 |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 | 2023-01-06 |
| 2 | 2023-02-08 | 2023-02-09 |

to select a new row each time a date is missing...

I have an sql I have tried here but it is designed for datetime-format and not just date-format....:

```
select *,min(act_date),max(act_date) from (select t.*,sum(case when prev_act_date >= act_date then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by ma_id,date_format(act_date,'%d-%m-%Y') order by act_date) grp from (select t.*,lag(act_date) over(partition by ma_id,date_format(act_date,'%d-%m-%Y') order by act_date) prev_act_date from XXXX.XXXX t where t.ma_id in (1,2)) t) t group by ma_id,date_format(act_date,'%d-%m-%Y'),grp order by min(act_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MySQL 8+:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(act_date,
                       LAG(act_date, 1, act_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) OVER
                           (PARTITION BY ma_id ORDER BY act_date)) - 1 AS diff
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(diff) OVER (PARTITION BY ma_id ORDER BY act_date) AS grp
    FROM cte
)

SELECT ma_id, MIN(act_date) AS start_date, MAX(act_date) AS end_date
FROM cte2
GROUP BY ma_id, grp
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

The first CTE computes the difference in days between adjacent records.  We use the long form of the `LAG()` window function, to ensure that the first record has a date difference of zero.  The second CTE sums this date difference to form a pseudo group.  Appreciate that the group number only changes when there is a date gap greater than one.  Finally, we aggregate by `ma_id` and pseudo group to find the start and end dates.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain step by step(using row_number() function):

###### 1. add a fixed date column to each row, like '19700101'

```
select yt.ma_id, yt.act_date, '19700101' from yourTable yt;
```

[image: add fixed column]

###### 2. add column diff of `datediff` from act_date to '19700101'

```
select yt.ma_id, yt.act_date, '19700101', datediff(date(yt.act_date), '19700101') as diff from yourTable yt;
```

[image: add diff]

###### 3. add column using row_number(partition by yt.ma_id order by yt.act_date) function to add another column to result

```
 select yt.ma_id, yt.act_date, '19700101', datediff(date(yt.act_date), '19700101') as diff, row_number() over (partition by yt.ma_id order by date(yt.act_date)) as row_num from yourTable yt;
```

[image: add row_num]

###### 4. calculate `diff` - `row_num`, we interested in column `diff_minus_row_num`

```
 select yt.ma_id, yt.act_date, '19700101', datediff(date(yt.act_date), '19700101') as diff, row_number() over (partition by yt.ma_id order by date(yt.act_date)) as row_num, datediff(date(yt.act_date), '19700101')  -  row_number() over (partition by yt.ma_id order by date(yt.act_date)) as diff_minus_row_num from yourTable yt;
```

[image: minus row num]

##### 5. use `group by` and `min`, `max` to get the results:

```
 select outside.ma_id, min(act_date) as 'start_date', max(act_date) as 'end_date' from (select yt.ma_id, yt.act_date, '19700101', datediff(date(yt.act_date), '19700101') as diff, row_number() over (partition by yt.ma_id order by date(yt.act_date)) as row_num, datediff(date(yt.act_date), '19700101')  -  row_number() over (partition by yt.ma_id order by date(yt.act_date)) as diff_minus_row_num from yourTable yt) outside group by outside.diff_minus_row_num order by 1,2;
```

[image: group by outside]